# Powershell Include In Project From Package Manager Console In Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

How can I perform "Include In Project" as in Solution Explorer but by using Powershell from the Package Manager Console?

Say my solution looks like this:

```
- SolutionA
  - ProjectA
    - ...Some Folders And Files...
  - ProjectB
    - FolderA
    - FolderB
      - FileA
      - FileB (Excluded from project)
```

How can I include FileB in my solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I am aware the package manager console exists for interacting with NuGet, not with Visual Studio. (EDIT: Ok, apparently you can access a `$dte` variable from within it to get access to Visual Studio's API.)

Answer (score 1):

Every now and then, when I need to see how to automate Visual Studio from a PowerShell script, I have a look at existing NuGet packages. One of them is the SQL Server Compact embedded database. If you open the corresponding [feed](https://nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact/4.0.8876.1) in [NuGet Package Explorer](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/59864), you'll see that it contains a module for automating VS called VS.psm1. That modules contains several useful functions, one of them allowing to do exactly what you want. Worth to have a look and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll take a look once I get back to my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use [ProjectItems.AddFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile.ASPX) to add the file into my project.

```
$myProject.ProjectItems.AddFromFile("PathOfFileOnDisk")
```

Where `$myProject` is a variable reference to the target project.